# How to check which calls to ccache were uncacheable

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, ccache

I have a cmake/C++/Qt project which I've started to onboard onto ccache. For that, I installed ccache with homebrew, set the build system generator as ninja, and added `-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=ccache` to the project.

and in the first test run I've got the following stats:

```
~$ ccache -s
Cacheable calls:    200 /  623 (32.10%)
  Hits:              56 /  200 (28.00%)
    Direct:          56 /   56 (100.0%)
    Preprocessed:     0 /   56 ( 0.00%)
  Misses:           144 /  200 (72.00%)
Uncacheable calls:  423 /  623 (67.90%)
Local storage:
  Cache size (GB): 0.01 / 5.00 ( 0.20%)
```

I wasn't counting such a high volume of uncacheable calls, and I wanted to take a look at which calls were uncacheable to see if there is something I can do about it.

Does anyone know if it's possible to troubleshoot calls to ccache to see which calls were deemed uncacheable?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you can do is to add `-v` or `--verbose` when running `ccache -s`. Then you'll see what type those uncacheable calls are.

However, you won't see which exact calls were uncacheable. To do that, you'll have to either [enable logging](https://ccache.dev/manual/4.7.4.html#config_log_file) or [enable the debug mode](https://ccache.dev/manual/4.7.4.html#config_debug) to get per-object log files. In the log file(s) you can see which commands were executed and why ccache considers some of them to be uncacheable.